# How to analysis this Json with retrofit2+rxjava2

Tags: json, retrofit, rx-android

I use `Retrofit.Builder()`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseApplication.HEAD_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

how to analysis this Json1 :

```
[
    {
        "type": "news",
        "id": "20170124013990",
        "column": "banner",
        "needUpdate": "0"
    },
    {
        "type": "news",
        "id": "20170124001763",
        "column": "banner",
        "needUpdate": "0"
    },
    {
        "type": "news",
        "id": "20170123019000",
        "column": "banner",
        "needUpdate": "0"
    },
    {
        "type": "news",
        "id": "20170123017746",
        "column": "banner",
        "needUpdate": "0"
    }
]
```

and the Json2,'20170122''20170123''20170124' are variable key :

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "data": {
        "20170122": {
            "atype": "0",
            "isCollect": "-1"
    },
    "20170123": {
        "atype": "1",
        "isCollect": "-1"
    },
    "20170124": {
        "atype": "0",
        "isCollect": "-1"
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Very sorry, because I don't know how to layout the text, so the code looks very disorderly, trouble for you to read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.